# how to properly configure using fluent api as data annotation not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

This is what i was trying to achieve but entity framework didn't let me do this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()      
                    .HasMany(u => u.Following)
                    .WithMany(u => u.Followers)
                    .Map(m =>
                            {
                                m.ToTable("FollowTables");
                                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                                m.MapRightKey("FollowId");
                            });
```

But if i use this code then in database, table is created but with no primary key in it.only two column got created.
If i use this code then proper table is created with primary key too in it.

```
    public class FollowTable
    {
    [Key]
    public int autoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Follow")]
    public int? FollowId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Follow { get; set; }
    }
```

here, autoId is primary key and UserId and FollowId both are foreign key to ApplicationUser class where UserId is user's own id and FollowId are the ids which user is following.

```
  autoId  UserId  FollowId
   1        4        11
   2        4        12
   3        4        13
```

but my ApplicationUser class structure is something like this :

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Followers = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        this.Following = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    // calculated properties
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Following { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followers { get; set; }
```

i want to use these collections badly.
But this code i think is creating a new table in database named dbo.ApplicationUserApplicationUsers with columns ApplicationUser_Id and ApplicationUser_Id1.
i dont want this table.also my code is too entering data into this table like this follow function:

```
   public virtual bool Follows(int userId, int accountId)
    {
        var targetUser = _context.Users
          .Where(u => u.Id == accountId && u.Id != userId)
          .Select(u => new
          {
              User = u,
              CanFollow = u.Followers.All(f => f.Id != userId)
          })
          .FirstOrDefault();
        if (targetUser == null || !targetUser.CanFollow) return false;
        var currentUser = _context.Users
          .Include(u => u.Following)
          .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
        if (currentUser == null) return false;
        if (currentUser.Following.All(u => u.Id != accountId))
        {
            currentUser.Following.Add(targetUser.User);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now, suggest me how to configure mapping with or without fluent api.i want to enter data in follow table not in table which was auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating two separate relationships. If you were dealing with something like "Friends", then that's a straight M2M: by virtue of me being your friend, you are also my friend. However, a user could follow many people and be followed by none, that means you need two separate relationships to to track that.

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Following { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followers { get; set; }

    public class Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        HasMany(m => m.Following).WithMany();
        HasMany(m => m.Followers).WithMany();
    }
}
```

Then in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUser.Mapping());
}
```

Entity Framework will handle the join tables. You don't need to worry about that, unless you need an M2M with a payload, like the date someone started following or the user started following someone else.

Comment: Dont know it will work or not will try it asap i got back to my lappy thnks for the help @Chris Pratt

Comment: well i tried this as u said, its now creating two extra tables in database dbo.ApplicationUserApplicationUser1 and dbo.ApplicationUserApplicationUsers u can try too @Chris Pratt

Comment: As it should. You have to two M2M relationships, so you need two join tables.